# How to set up GKE configuration in a yml file for Django app?

Tags: django, google-kubernetes-engine

I am following below doc in the link to deploy the django application in the **Google Kubernetes Engine**.
[Setting up your GKE configuration in a yml file](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/kubernetes-engine#setting_up_your_configuration_)

In the step [Setting up your GKE configuration](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/kubernetes-engine#setting_up_your_configuration_), there is yml file called `polls.yaml`. Where should I find this file ? If it doesn't exist yet, where should I create it and follow what template ?

Comment: I see all the `yaml` files are attached to the guide in [Understanding the code](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/kubernetes-engine#understanding_the_code) section. Were you able to find what you've missed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is the polls.yaml [file](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/kubernetes_engine/django_tutorial) you were looking for.

I used the following info

```
git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples.git

cd python-docs-samples/kubernetes_engine/django_tutorial
```

in order to locate your polls.yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

oh I missed the before step i took one week ago so the polls refer to the polls cluster I created before:

`gcloud container clusters create polls \ --scopes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email","cloud-platform" \ --num-nodes 4 --zone "us-central1-a"`